# How I can change appCompat(android)

Tags: android, sdk, android-appcompat

Sorry for my english. I update in `compileSdkVersion 23` but my project use `org.apache.http*` and all is crash. I want compile in `compileSdkVersion 22` what I before do. But if I change this, I have error

> Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

And I don't know how fix this. My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.home.smart.home"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":slidingLibrary")
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

but project still have this:

[image]

How I can use appCompat **v22** ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the support libraries `v23` you have to use `compileSdkVersion 23` otherwise you can have some issues like

`Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse`.

You can use the support libraries v22 if you want to compile with API22.

The API 23 (Android 6.0) **removed** the Apache HTTP client and the package `org.apache.http*` .
You can read more info [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).
You can use the `HttpURLConnection` class instead or you can switch to [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the last line of your code that is

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

You & I updated the appcompat to 23.0.0. I'm not able to run it as 22 but if you change it to 23 you will be able to run your project.... my build.gradle module:app file is like below & is working good

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.inzi.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Comment: if i change this, my all project get me error, becouse i use `org.apache.http*` and  `compileSdkVersion 23` remove this

Comment: @g8214435 Read the answer below.It explain you why you have the problem with org.apache.http package.

Answer (score 1):

set the compileSdkVersion to 23 as line 3 below & at last line, check the latest code it may help you

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.inzi.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```